# Android - showDialog method, problems with default case in switch statement

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-dialog

I'm programming some custom dialogs and I've run into some trouble with the `showDialog` method. For some reason, when I pass the id of the Dialog I want to create to the `showDialog` method, it executes both the intended case and the default case.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(c.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(c.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(c.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated your code with following code,

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = null;

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(c.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(c.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(c.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        dpd =  new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    break;     // you forgot this line in your code
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: because break is after the return statement, and if it is before the return then it will not return the DatePickerDialog

Comment: Therefore, attempting to add the `break;` statement hasn't helped me at all.

Comment: Hmm... it seems that my problem is elsewhere then. I really wish I could resize the DatePicker widget...

Comment: well in that case, i would suggest you to upload whole code to help you better

Answer (score 1):

`break;` in Your First Case :

If cant Work See this http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidDialogs/article.html

Comment: I've tried `break;`. The problem is that Eclipse throws an error here, stating the `break;` statement is "unreachable code". Even trying `return super.onCreateDialog(id)` gives me the same problem of the default case being handled anyways.